# pathForDirectory method for NSBundle?

Tags: ios, path, directory, nsbundle

If I include a folder in my bundle (a real folder, the blue ones, not the yellow groups), how can I get the path for that folder from my bundle?  The method I would usually use is...

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:______];
```

...but what "type" is a directory?  Is there a "type" to use, or is there another method for accessing the paths of directories within the bundle?

Or am I going about this all wrong, and there's some other way for including folders of accessible documents in the bundle?

Comment: Directories can have extensions too. If yours doesn't have one, pass @"" for the `type` parameter.

Comment: @Cristik  Huh.  Well whadya know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories can have extensions too. If yours doesn't have one, just pass @"" for the `type` parameter, `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` works for directories too, not only files. At the end, a directory is also a resource :)

Answer (score 0):

As per a suggestion in the comments, it turns out you can use an empty string to refer to folders.  So a folder called "myFolder" would be accessible using...

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFolder" ofType:@""];
```

Hope this helps anyone else who wasn't expecting it to be so easy...

Answer (score 0):

As you're adding a folder by your own, you know the name of the folder, so you can get the path like this:

```
NSString *myDirectoryName = @"myDirectory";
NSString *absolutePathToMyDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:myDirectoryName];
```

You'll have to test if this path exist with `NSFileManager`.

Otherwise you can still use the method you're using, the type can be `nil`, so you can call it like this

```
NSString *absolutePathToMyDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myDirectoryName ofType:nil];
```

and then testing if the result is `nil` or not.

```
if(absolutePathToMyDirectory) {
    // do stuff related to this path
}
```